# How to filter based on id which contains specific name in another column in an excel file using Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have a excel file containing three columns as shown below,

| ID | Name | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1136 | GG Daubringen | 2019-04-08 |
| 1136 | Manheinm | 2020-06-16 |
| 1136 | Manheinm Streitkof | 2020-07-24 |
| 1136 | Staufenberg | 2020-08-15 |
| 1136 | Stürcken | 2021-03-05 |
| 1136 | Stürcken (FTTH) | 2021-09-13 |
| 1234 | Lerbeck | 2019-04-18 |
| 1234 | BAd oyehausen | 2020-06-26 |
| 1234 | Werre Park | 2020-07-14 |
| 1234 | Werre Park (FTTH) | 2020-08-25 |
| 1234 | Werre Park (FTTH) | 2021-03-15 |
| 1234 | Bad oyehausen | 2021-09-23 |

Is it possible to filter out the **ID** for which the name starts without **(FTTH)** and end the name without **(FTHH)**, For example the first 1st **ID 1136** has the name doesn't start with (FTTH) but ends with (FTTH), but I want to filter out the ID which doesn't start with (FTTH) and also doesn't end with (FTTH) as in the **ID 1234** , is it possible to filter it using python ??

Expecting the result to be like,

| ID |
| --- |
| 1234 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can aggregate [`GroupBy.first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.first.html)
[`GroupBy.last`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.last.html) first and then filter indices for [`Series.str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) and [`Series.str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html):

```
df1 = df.groupby('ID')['Name'].agg(['first','last'])

i = df1.index[~df1['first'].str.startswith('(FTTH)') & ~df1['last'].str.endswith('(FTTH)')]
print (i)
#Int64Index([1234], dtype='int64', name='ID')
```

If need values in list:

```
L = i.tolist()
[1234]
```

If need DataFrame:

```
out = i.to_frame(index=False)
print (out)
     ID
0  1234
```

If need `first` without `(FTTH)` and `last` with `(FTTH)` use:

```
i = df1.index[~df1['first'].str.startswith('(FTTH)') & df1['last'].str.endswith('(FTTH)')]
```

Comment: Kindly can you explain what does the code represents in the line "Int64Index([1234], dtype='int64', name='ID')"

Comment: I think you have got the other way around, the name should start without (FTTH) and end without (FTTH)

Comment: @Vicky - `i` is `ID` converted to index.

Comment: Ok, I understood the concept, but what exactly does the line 'Int64Index([1234], dtype='int64', name='ID')' do. Because if there there many ID instead of 1234 what would be the case ?? kindly explain

Comment: @Vicky - It filter `ID` from `df1.index` - unique `ID` values

Comment: Ok, if in case I have multiple ID's instead of 1234 what would be the case in the line Int64Index([1234], dtype='int64', name='ID').

Comment: @Vicky - then get `Int64Index([1234,10,25], dtype='int64', name='ID')` if also match `10` and `25`

Comment: Because I get an error  'NameError: name 'Int64Index' is not defined'
If I write is as Int64Index([], dtype='int64', name='ID')

Comment: What If there are many number of Id which cannot be added into the Index, mine have 924 unique ID'S. How is it possible to enter all the ID ?

Comment: @Vicky - If use this solution, in `df1.index` get all `df['ID']` values without duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

```
s = ~df['Name'].str.endswith('(FTTH)')
s.groupby(df['ID']).agg(['first', 'last']).all(axis=1)[lambda x:x].reset_index()[['ID']]
```

output:

```
    ID
0   1234
```